# Let the user choose among a set of default colors

Tags: matlab, user-interface, colors

Can I have something like this in the GUI of matlab to let the user choose between a set of default colors?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a loot at [`uisetcolor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uisetcolor.html).

And while you are at it, [here's](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/predefined-dialog-boxes.html) a list of pre-defined, commonly used, out-of-the-box UI elements Mathworks has made just for you!

Enjoy